# Kafka takes ~30 minutes for new messages to be consumed

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Running one consumer, three brokers, one producer.  Having issues with messages being produced into kafka, but there being a roughly 35 minute delay between production and the consumer being able to ingest the messages.  This is specifically, though possibly not exclusively seen when kafka has been exhausted of messages, the consumer continues to run, and then more messages are produced.

Unsure of broker/producer configuration, but can query sysadmin with questions

```
Consumer config:

 metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 15000
    partition.assignment.strategy =org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    bootstrap.servers = [myip]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    enable.auto.commit = false
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    interceptor.classes = null
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id =
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    max.poll.records = 10
    check.crcs = true
    request.timeout.ms = 360000
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    group.id = hitsconsumer
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.key.password = null
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    session.timeout.ms = 300000
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
```

Comment: Are you reusing the same group.id each time it runs? Maybe you have several consumers in a group and they are each having to timeout and get kicked out of the consumer group until the real one get a chance to consume from a single partition. You might want to run bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh during the delay to see who is in the consumer group for that topic

Comment: All three threads have same group id, consumer doesnt stop running.  There definitely is a delay between completing consumption and new messages getting produced.  Assuming it is a timing out/doesnt let it reregister with groupid for a while, what would be the solution?

Comment: What version are you running? Are all three threads in the same consumer app are are you running three separate consumers? Kafka 0.9 and higher does not support multiple threads per consumer so you should try running with a single thread. Also are you sure you have three or more partitions to you topic? Running three consumers in a group only works if they each have a dedicated partition to read from.

Comment: Version 2.11  Each thread has its own consumer, exactly the same number as there are partitions.  All consumers with same groupid.  Happens even when I reduce it to a single thread.

Order of operations is:  Broker has many messages, consumer runs, consumes everything, broker sits empty for a few hours, new messages produced, consumer gets 0 messages from kafka for about 40 minutes before rejoining broker and consuming as normal.